# Why can't I use a function return value as a parameter?

Tags: c, function, enums, parameters

Here is the code that I am having trouble with.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getplayerone (void);
int getplayertwo (void);
void output (int getplayerone (), int getplayertwo ());

enum choice
{ r, p, s };
typedef enum choice Choice;

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  //getplayerone();
  // getplayertwo();
  output (getplayerone (), getplayertwo ());
  return 0;
}

int
getplayerone (void)
{
  char choice1;
  int choice1int;
  printf ("Player-1 it is your turn!\n");
  printf ("Please enter your choice (p)aper, (r)ock, ir (s)cissors: ");
  scanf (" %c", &choice1);
  if (choice1 == 'r' || choice1 == 'R')
    {
      choice1int = 0;
    }
  else if (choice1 == 'p' || choice1 == 'P')
    {
      choice1int = 1;
    }
  else if (choice1 == 's' || choice1 == 'S')
    {
      choice1int = 2;
    }
  if (choice1int == 0)
    {

    }

  return choice1int;
}

int
getplayertwo (void)
{
  char choice2;
  int choice2int;
  printf ("\nPlayer-2 it is your turn!\n");
  printf ("Please enter your choice (p)aper, (r)ock, ir (s)cissors: ");
  scanf (" %c", &choice2);
  if (choice2 == 'r' || choice2 == 'R')
    {
      choice2int = 0;
    }
  else if (choice2 == 'p' || choice2 == 'P')
    {
      choice2int = 1;
    }
  else if (choice2 == 's' || choice2 == 'S')
    {
      choice2int = 2;
    }

  return choice2int;
}

void
output (int getplayerone (), int getplayertwo ())
{

  Choice p1choice = getplayerone ();
  Choice p2choice = getplayertwo ();

  if (p1choice == r && p2choice == r)
    {
      printf ("Draw");
    }
  else if (p1choice == r && p2choice == p)
    {
      printf ("Player 2 wins");
    }
  else if (p1choice == r && p2choice == s)
    {
      printf ("Player 1 wins");
    }
  else if (p1choice == s && p2choice == r)
    {
      printf ("Player 2 wins");
    }
  else if (p1choice == s && p2choice == p)
    {
      printf ("Player 1 wins");
    }
  else if (p1choice == s && p2choice == s)
    {
      printf ("Draw");
    }
  else if (p1choice == p && p2choice == r)
    {
      printf ("Player 1 wins");
    }
  else if (p1choice == p && p2choice == p)
    {
      printf ("Draw");
    }
  else if (p1choice == p && p2choice == s)
    {
      printf ("Player 2 wins");
    }

  printf ("%d", p1choice);
}
```

I am required to use an enumerated type to get the input of each player.
This is a simple rock, paper scissors game.
I am having trouble with my output function types and I am getting the following errors in the function call, as well as when I assign Choice p1choice in the function body.

```
Incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type 'int (*)()'

Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address = 0x0)
```

Thank you for the input and help!

Comment: please, for ease of readability and understanding, consistently indent the code.  indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.

Comment: this line: `output( getplayerone(),  getplayertwo());` may result in the 'playertwo' being retrieved first, due to the ordering of the evaluation of parameters is not defied in the standard, so is implementation dependent

Comment: the posted code contains many instances of random blank lines.  for readability, it is best to separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line and not place other/random blank lines in a function body

Comment: the testing of the contents of `choice1` would be much clearer and more comprehensive if performed via a `switch()` statement rather than a smattering of `if then else` statements

Comment: the variable `choice1int` is not initialized and (for instance) if the user entered `Q` it would still be uninitialized when it is returned from the call to `getplayerone()`    BTW: it is best to 'lower camel case' variable and function names, for readability.   These same considerations apply to the function: `getplayertwo()`

Comment: since the allowed value in the enum `Choice` are `r` `s` and `p` (which are lower case) it would be best to pass the input character to `tolower()` (found in the header file: `<ctype.h>`)

Comment: it is a poor programming practice to have multiple names those only difference is capitalization.

Comment: the posted code does not cleanly compile.  when the arguments to `main()` are not going to be used, then use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: this prototype: `void output(int getplayerone(),int getplayertwo());` is not correct. (your compiler should have told you that)  Suggest: `void output(int, int);`

Comment: The functions: `getplayerone()` and `getplayertwo()` do exactly the same thing, except for a `printf()` statement (which could be selected via a passed in parameter.)   strongly suggest eliminating one of those functions.

Answer (score 1):

you call output this way:

```
output( getplayerone(),  getplayertwo());
```

call it with the functions itself:

```
output( getplayerone,  getplayertwo);
```

Comment: @sg7 in the original code , the `output` function calls the function pointers passed to it. Which would work fine if the change described in this answer is made.

Comment: @M.M Thank you for your comment!  Yes, we could call `output( getplayerone,  getplayertwo);`  if we change prototype from  `void output (int getplayerone (), int getplayertwo ());`  to `void output (int (*f1)(),int (*f2)());`

Comment: @sg7 those two prototypes are identical in effect. The `*` is optional for function pointers in function parameter lists and there is no need for redundant parentheses if you omit the `*`.

Comment: @M.M You are absolutely right!  Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

> Why can't I use a function return value as a parameter?

You can. This is the proper call:

```
output( getplayerone(),  getplayertwo());
```

If

```
void output(int r1,int r2); // also `void output(int, int);`  would do
void output(int r1,int r2){
//...
}
```

Since you declared your function `output` as:

```
void output(int getplayerone(),int getplayertwo());
void output(int getplayerone(),int getplayertwo()){
//...
}
```

You need to pass function pointers as parameters:

```
   output(getplayerone, getplayertwo);
```

The small example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getplayerone (void);
int getplayertwo (void);

void output (int ret_getplayerone, int ret_getplayertwo);
void output1 (int (*f1)(), int (*f2)() );

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int r1, r2;
    // 1.
    output (r1=getplayerone(), r2=getplayertwo());// OK, but there is no need to do so 
    output ( getplayerone(),   getplayertwo() );  // OK!
    //output ( getplayerone,   getplayertwo );    // wrong!
    // 2.
    output1 ( getplayerone, getplayertwo );       // pass the function pointers

    return 0;
}

int getplayerone (void)
{
    return 1;
}

int getplayertwo (void)
{
    return 2;
}

void output (int ret_getplayerone, int ret_getplayertwo)
{
 printf ("Output()   %d , %d\n", ret_getplayerone, ret_getplayertwo );
}

void output1 (int (*f1)(), int (*f2)() )
{
 printf ("\nOutput1()  %d , %d\n", (*f1)(), (*f2)() );
}
```

Output:

```
Output()   1 , 2
Output()   1 , 2

Output1()  1 , 2
```

Answer (score 0):

The function prototype is wrong, it should be

```
void output(int playerone, int playertwo);
```

Comment: Or even just `void output(int, int);`, but in any case it's a function that takes integers, and it's declared as a function that takes function pointers.

Comment: When I make this change, I get an error in the function definition saying "Conflicting types for 'output'".

Comment: @RyanAllen You need to change both,